# how to get size of entity in google app engine without fetching the entity?

Tags: google-app-engine

how to get size of entity in google app engine without fetching the entity ( with only key ? ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - you have to fetch the entity, then compute its size (however you want to measure that).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3127

ok an issue created. Thanks for reply.

Comment: This is a feature request, not a defect. It's also not terribly likely to be implemented: Getting just the size would take just as long as fetching it, and require very nearly the same API CPU time.